# actionscript 3 popup window - not js

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

Im doing a program in AS3 and, i'm trying to do the following:
Lets say I have a button, which have onClick event, and when the event is triggered, the popup window will appear. 
And in this popup window there is going to be an animation (countdown) of 2020 (this is just an example).

Is there a way to do this without javascript. Because i'm not doing this for website, its going to be a animation.

Hope i was clear.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at TitleWindow? I am a flex developer and i just use PopupManager to load TitleWindow.

Comment: If this has no relevance to js - I think you should remove it from your title as it is misleading and can cause confusion. So to understand your issue - You would like to click an object on the stage and the appearance of a pop-up like object displaying a clock should be shown?

Comment: @Glycerine that is correct. I just want that the popup would fade in. not some redirect stuff

Comment: Are you using any libraries, such as TweenMax?

Comment: no. I'm quite a new guy in this action scripting stuff

Answer (score 0):

In Flash,create a movie clip, give it an instance name of "countdown_mc", put the countdown animation inside it.This will be your "alert" type window.

Now, in the movieclip containing "countdown_mc", add a new layer and on the same frame bring up the action editor(F9) and write the following: countdown_mc.visible=false;

When you push the button it should make countdown_mc.visible=true and maybe do an optional growing animation;

Also on this frame add a listener for countdown_mc so that when the user clicks on the window it disappears(countdown_mc.visible=false);

For animations add download tweenmax from http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/, extract the archive in the folder that contains your fla and add the following to your code:

import com.greensock.*;
TweenMax.from(countdown_mc,0.5,{scaleX:0,scaleY:0});